# Winner checker in Sudoku

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, label, sudoku

I am currently working on my own Sudoku project in Tkinter. I have managed to make a grid with labels and entry values. I am working on a submit button that will check whether the player has won or not. I need the program to go through all the numbers and compare each number to its row, column and grid.

```
global grid_entries
grid_entries = []
for i in range(9):
    row_entries = []
    for j in range(9):
        cell_value = puzzle[i][j]
        x = j * 40 + 20 + (j // 3) * 5
        y = i * 40 + 20 + (i // 3) * 5
        if cell_value == '':
            entry = Entry(canvas, font=("Calibri", 20), width=2, justify='center', fg='Blue', bd=2, bg='white', relief='ridge')
            entry.grid(row=i, column=j)
            canvas.create_window(x, y, window=entry)
        else:
            label = Label(canvas, text=cell_value, fg='black', font=('Calbri', 20), bd = 2, bg = 'white', relief='ridge', width=2)
            label.grid(row=i, column=j)
            canvas.create_window(x, y, window=label)
        row_entries.append(entry if cell_value == '' else label)
    grid_entries.append(row_entries)
```

This is my loop to create labels and entry boxes for the Sudoku pattern, and to store any entry value that has been added. I don't know how to loop the numbers and compare them.

I have wrote this to see if I can get each individual value.

```
def submit_action():
    for row in grid_entries:
        for cell in row:
            if isinstance(cell, Entry):
                print(cell.get('text'), end=' ')
            elif isinstance(cell, Label):
                print(cell.cget('text'), end=' ')
            else:
                print('Empty', end=' ')
```

It did not work.

Comment: Why not create a function that checks if a number works in a given position? And then run a loop that executes that function on every number in the 2d list.